# How a non-defined local method variable can override a method?

Tags: ruby

Given the code:

```
class Someone

  def full_name
    if false # on purpose
      # We'll never reach this point because of the `false` above
      first_name = "Other" # So how this code can affect 
                           # the instance variable?
    end
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def first_name
    "First"
  end

  def last_name
    "Last"
  end
end

s = Someone.new

s.full_name
# => "Last"
```

Why `s.full_name == "Last"`.

In other words, how `first_name` method can be overriden until **we don't pass through the if statement** ?…

To be clear, why ruby doesn't act as… javascript, for instance:

```js
class Someone {

  get full_name() {
    if ( false ) {
      // In JS, that doesn't override
      // first_name
      this.first_name = "Other";
    }
    return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
  }

  get first_name() {
    return "First";
  }
  
  get last_name() {
    return "Last";
  }
}

let s = new Someone();

console.log("s.full_name() = ", s.full_name);
```

`s.full_name` will be egal to `"First Last"`, not to `"Last"` as in ruby.

It's my effort to understand ruby, not to blame it! (I love passionnément Ruby)

Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: Very very very sorry for typo in question ("override").

Comment: There was an answer here before (it's been deleted) that I thought had a decent explanation. The key is that the Ruby parser decides whether to treat it as a local variable before the interpreter ever sees whether it's run.

Comment: Thanks, @Max. Perfectly clear, and it's what I suspected. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Max You may be interested by the quotation from The Pickaxe about the heuristic used by Ruby in my answer.

Comment: @BernardK Thanks! I'd been looking for an authoritative reference, so I'm glad you found that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have a great respect for your Ruby knowledge and SO contribution, but I disagree that this is a duplicate. The other post is about "why a variable defined in a falsy block exists ?", this one is about the heuristic that Ruby uses to choose between variable and method call. See also tadman 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

We need to trace it to understand what's going on.

```
class Someone

  def full_name
    if false # on purpose
      # We'll never reach this point because of the `false` above
      first_name = "Other" # <--- first_name stored as variable
    end

    puts '---> about to call methods first_name and last_name ... or not'
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}" # <--- big decision here
    puts '... which method wal called ???'
  end

  def first_name
    puts 'passes in first_name'
    "First"
  end

  def last_name
    puts 'passes in last_name'
    "Last"
  end
end

s = Someone.new

puts s.full_name.inspect
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:10: warning: possibly useless use of a literal in void context (because of the following puts)
---> about to call methods first_name and last_name ... or not
passes in last_name
... which method wal called ???
nil (value returned by the last puts in full_name)
```

So why the expression `"#{first_name} #{last_name}"` calls `last_name` but not `first_name` ? The answer is in [The Pickaxe](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0) :

> **Variable/Method Ambiguity**
>
> When Ruby sees a name such as a in an
>   expression, it needs to determine whether it is a local variable
>   reference or a call to a method with no parameters. To decide which is
>   the case, Ruby uses a heuristic. As Ruby parses a source file, it
>   keeps track of symbols that have been assigned to. It assumes that
>   these symbols are variables. When it subsequently comes across a
>   symbol that could be a variable or a method call, it checks to see
>   whether it has seen a prior assignment to that symbol. If so, it
>   treats the symbol as a variable; otherwise, it treats it as a method
>   call.
>
> ...
>
> Note that the assignment does not have to be executed—Ruby
>   just has to have seen it.

This is exactly the situation you've encountered. Rename `first_name` to something else :

```
  xxxfirst_name = "Other" # So how this code can affect
```

and ... tada !

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:10: warning: possibly useless use of a literal in void context
t.rb:6: warning: assigned but unused variable - xxxfirst_name
---> about to call methods first_name and last_name ... or not
passes in first_name
passes in last_name
... which method wal called ???
nil
```

or, without the last `puts` :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:6: warning: assigned but unused variable - xxfirst_name
---> about to call methods first_name and last_name ... or not
passes in first_name
passes in last_name
"First Last"
```

> ```
>    first_name = "Other" # So how this code can affect 
>                         # the instance variable?
> ```

Your code has no instance variable (beginning with an @). `first_name` defines a local variable which is discarded when the method ends.

Add `inspect` in the expression :

```
"#{first_name.inspect} #{last_name}"
```

The result is now :

```
passes in last_name
"nil Last"
```

As the `if` was not executed, the variable is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the behaviour happens during the parsing process.

To investigate, you can use [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html).

```
require 'ripper'
require 'pp'

pp Ripper.sexp("a = 3")
# [:program,
#  [[:assign, [:var_field, [:@ident, "a", [1, 0]]], [:@int, "3", [1, 4]]]]]

pp Ripper.sexp("a = 3; a")
# [:program,
#  [[:assign, [:var_field, [:@ident, "a", [1, 0]]], [:@int, "3", [1, 4]]],
#   [:var_ref, [:@ident, "a", [1, 7]]]]]

pp Ripper.sexp("def a; end; a")
# [:program,
#  [[:def,
#    [:@ident, "a", [1, 4]],
#    [:params, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
#    [:bodystmt, [[:void_stmt]], nil, nil, nil]],
#   [:vcall, [:@ident, "a", [1, 12]]]]]

pp Ripper.sexp("if false; a = 3; end; def a; end; a")
# [:program,
#  [[:if,
#    [:var_ref, [:@kw, "false", [1, 3]]],
#    [[:assign, [:var_field, [:@ident, "a", [1, 10]]], [:@int, "3", [1, 14]]]],
#    nil],
#   [:def,
#    [:@ident, "a", [1, 26]],
#    [:params, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
#    [:bodystmt, [[:void_stmt]], nil, nil, nil]],
#   [:var_ref, [:@ident, "a", [1, 34]]]]]
```

You can play a bit with this great library and look for `var_ref`s and `vcall`s.

Comment: Thanks @Eric_Duminil !

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing little bit of Ruby's *variable vs. method call* ambiguity, but it's actually fairly easy to resolve if you know what you're looking for. The easiest way to find out what something's being interpreted as is to ask:

```
def full_name
  p defined?(first_name)
end
```

In this case you get `"method"` since in that code there's no reason to believe otherwise.

Once you add a local variable, though, *even one that never gets used*, the interpretation changes, but it only changes *after* that line where the shift in usage occurs:

```
def first_name
    "First"
end

def full_name
  p defined?(first_name)

  if (false)
    first_name = :not_used
  end

  p defined?(first_name)
end

full_name
```

Now you get `"method"` for the first one, but `"local-variable"` for the second, as the interpretation has shifted. The very presence of `first_name =` has caused this twist. It cannot be undone in that block, the only thing you can do is avoid conflicting names.

You can also call `local_variables` to find out which names are *potentially* variables, as those are known in advance.

Comment: Thanks for you explaination, @tadman! In fact, it's an issue I used to uncounter when I wrote (too huge) programs with no testing. Hopefully, it never happens again but this question of noob never left my mind.

Comment: I use my recently acquired editor privilege to make your code work as described :) Without `def first_name`, the first `p defined?(first_name)` returns `nil` instead of `"method"`.